# Adding to a sum variable produces a "reals can't be synthesized" error in verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, error

First, a disclaimer that this is my first time using verilog and I don't really know anything. My code is as follows:

```
module trapverilog(
    input CLK,
    input SIGNAL,
     input x,
    output reg OUT
    );

reg[1:0] yreg;
real sum = 0;

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    yreg = SIGNAL; //should shift automatically
    sum = ((yreg[0] + yreg[1])*x/2) + sum; //treats x as plain h, change if treated as h/2
    OUT = sum;
end

endmodule
```

It produces an error saying that `real` data types can't be synthesized referring to the `sum = ((yreg[0]...` line. What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

---

The intent here is to create an FPGA that can perform the trapezoidal integration method which is just $$A = \frac{(b-a)(y_1+y_2)}{2}$$ In my program I'm taking $$\frac{b-a}{2}$$ as an input `x` and I'm also talking in a clock signal `CLK` and a signal to be integrated, `SIGNAL`.

I create a two spot register, `yreg`, with and when `CLK` is high I set `yreg = SIGNAL` intending to shift the old value into the next slot - that is, I end up with y<sub>1</sub> shifting to y<sub>2</sub> and the new value goes into y<sub>1</sub>. Then I calculate the area following the formula given above and add it to `sum` and set the output, `OUT` equal to `sum`. The problem in this case being that `sum` can't be added to.

There are probably other errors that I don't know about so I apologize for those in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HDLs might contain constructs which cannot be translated into a hardware and only good for simulations. Apparently the `real` type is one of these.

Comment: You have other problems too. There is not automatic shift. You have to make it explicit. And you should use the non blocking assignment (<=) for assignments inside always @posedge.

Comment: And then you'll probably see the latency bigger than you need because you have extra pipeline stages that you don't want (assign to sum as a flip flop and then out is another one). Put non flip flop assignments outside that always block (use an assign or a combinational always block).

Comment: You will probably learn a lot if you read the Xilinx [Synthesis Guide](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse232/xilinx/sim.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rally as simple as the message says. The tool can't map reals to hardware. I don't know if your target chip has hardware real support. But if it does, you likely need to instantiate that block.

Comment: Is there an alternative type that would work for my purposes? My target chip is a Spartan 6 FPGA Development Board.

Comment: You need to adapt your calculations for integer or fixed-point